# Conflicting stdin when running multiple consoles

Tags: windows, rust, command

The following code (compiled for `windows`) iteratively requests a command from the console.

If the command is `exit`, the iteration (and program) is terminated;
if the command is `new_console`, a new console is opened with a new instance of the program and the iteration continues;
otherwise, the iteration continues with an error message.

So if I type `new_console` in the first instance, I should get two consoles where I can type commands and interact with each program instance.

Everything works like this, except that I can only enter a command on one console, and that console changes randomly after each command.

For this reason, I suspect `stdin` for consoles is conflicting.

How to avoid this?

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> { 
    use std::process::Command;
    use std::os::windows::process::CommandExt;
    let mut args = std::env::args();
    let command_self = args.next().unwrap();
    let mut childs = Vec::new();
    let mut loop_on = true;
    let mut stdin_lines = std::io::stdin().lines();
    while loop_on {
        println!("Enter line:");
        let entry = match stdin_lines.next() {
            None => break, Some(r) => r,
        }?;
        match entry.as_str() {
            "exit" => loop_on = false,
            "new_console" => {
                childs.push({
                    Command::new(&command_self)
                            .creation_flags(0x00000410)
                            .spawn()
                            .expect("failed to execute process")
                });                            
            },
            c => {
                println!("unknown command: {c}");
            },
        }    
    }
    childs.into_iter().for_each(|mut c| { let _ = c.wait(); } );
    Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not that familiar with the details of handles on Windows, I can say that this would be expected on Unix.  When you spawn a new process, unless you specify a new input source, the file descriptor is inherited, and both the old and new process share the exact same file description.  Thus, when you provide input, it will be read by exactly one process, and which one is not well defined.

In general, unless you know what you're doing, you don't want two programs to be trying to read from the same file descriptor (handle on Windows).  If your goal is to let the new program read from the standard input, then you should wait for the command to exit by doing something like this:

```rust
let child = Command::new(&command_self)
                .creation_flags(0x00000410)
                .spawn()
                .expect("failed to execute process");
let _ = child.wait();
```

That will effectively cause the parent process to wait for the child to exit, and therefore what the parent *won't* be doing is trying to read standard input.  Once the child has exited, the parent will resume its loop and proceed as normal.

On Unix, you can also call `exec` on `Command` instead of `spawn`, which will replace the current process entirely with your new one, which means that the old process will cease to exist (having been replaced) and therefore no longer try to read from standard input.  However, while such functionality is possible on Windows (after all, Cygwin implements it), it's non-trivial, and is not included in the Rust standard library.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about this point. So I looked for a Windows based solution. In the end, I found that the "start" command of "cmd.exe" avoids this problem (my answer).

Answer (score 0):

In the end, the answer was surprisingly simple: use the `start` command from `cmd.exe` to create a new console.
This results in cmd.exe running with the arguments "/C start .\folder\prog.exe".

```
fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> { 
    use std::process::Command;
    let mut args = std::env::args();
    let command_self = format!("/C start .\\{}", args.next().unwrap());
    let mut loop_on = true;
    let mut stdin_lines = std::io::stdin().lines();
    while loop_on {
        println!("Enter line:");
        let entry = match stdin_lines.next() {
            None => break, Some(r) => r,
        }?;
        match entry.as_str() {
            "exit" => loop_on = false,
            "new_console" => {
                    let _ = Command::new("cmd.exe")
                            .arg(&command_self)
                            .spawn()
                            .expect("failed to execute process").wait();
            },
            c => {
                println!("unknown command: {c}");
            },
        }    
    }
    Ok(())
}
```